# Why my windows search index is 255 GB in size and how do I reduce it?

Tags: windows-10, search, search-indexing

[image]

I try to search something on one note and it doesn't work.

So I check windows indexing service.

It says

> Indexing in progress. Search result might not complete during this
> time

I look for that on the web and found https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/windows-search-performance-issues

It says to check the size of Windows.edp

I checked and the size is 255 GB.

How can it be that big?

How do I know what problems cause it to be that big? my files aren't that big.

Rebuilding the index allow me to find my items in notepad. However, windows.edp doesn't get deleted. I wonder why.

Update:
I hardly change anything but now it's only 7GB

Comment: According to the docs.microsoft.com page, the file extension is `.edb` not `.edp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It says to check the size of Windows.edp I checked and the size is 255
> GB. How can it be that big?

255 GB is way too large.  This is because you are trying to index too much (complete drives).

Look at your locations: You are trying to Index your entire Drives C: and D: .   That will take a long time and may not yield appropriate results.

Limit your search to Email and Documents - depends on your file structure.

When you reset your locations, go into Advanced Index Settings and rebuild your index to shrink it.

My EDB is 3GB with 170,000 items of email and documents indexed. Starting from scratch, it will take overnight (12 hours) to fully index. Do allow time.

Here is my EDB and Locations for Indexing.

.

[image: Index DB size]

.

[image: Location Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have reduced the number of indexed disk folders, rebuild the
index in *Start > Indexing Options > Advanced > Rebuild* :

[image]

[image]